# Detect if visitor is on index page with client side scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to detect if a visitor is on the index page or domain root with client side scripting?

I figure javascript would be the best method as I would like to append a value to an image file based on wether a visitor is on the home page or not.

Non-index page:

```
<img src="/img/logo.png" />
```

Index page:

```
<img src="/img/logo-home.png" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var homeUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
if ( document.URL == homeUrl ){
    // true
}else{
    // false    
}
```

Now put an id on your image tag in the HTML:

```
<img src="/img/logo-home.png" id="logotype" />
```

Now you can easily find the image tag with javascript and change the source of the image depending on where you are on the site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var homeUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
    var logotypeHome = '/img/logo-home.png';
    var logotypeGeneral = '/img/logo-general.png';

    if ( document.URL == homeUrl ){
        $('#logotype').attr("src", logotypeHome);
    }else{
        $('#logotype').attr("src", logotypeGeneral);   
    }

});
```

I would still strongly recommend to go for a server-side solution for a thing like this. If the client doesn't have JavaScript enabled this will not work. Also there could be a flash on the image when the javascript changes the logo source.

Comment: `document.location.href` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Brilliant. How would I go about setting a value and writing that to the document?

Comment: Don't forget the check the index file too if there is one ... http://www.example.com/index.php or http://www.example.com/home/ might be the homepage too.

Comment: @sterling - I could be wrong, but I'm guessing what you really need is a server-side scripting language.  Using Javascript to tweak things like this on 99% of your pages doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: @scunliffe - I agree, there are many ways this could be accomplished server side, but in this specific scenario on a very small site, I am looking for a client side solution. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 8):

An other solution , without Base URL.

```
if ( window.location.pathname === '/' ){
    //code for index page

}else{
    //other tasks    
}
```

Comment: Way better, since it doesn't require hard coding your domain in your javascript..